# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. laravel 6

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-6

I am trying to send a form with an image using AJAX, but apparently I have a problem with the route. I put the route as it is and it does not send me information. It gives me a 404 error.

```js
$('#btn_enviar').click(function() {
  $(this).html('Sending..');

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    data: $('#profesor').serialize(),
    url: "{{ URL('/SuperAdmin/StoreProfesor') }}",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('Error:', data);
    }
  });
});
```

```php
Route::POST('/SuperAdmin/StoreProfesor', 'ProfesorController@store')->name('/SuperAdmin/StoreProfesor');
```

Comment: Check in your `php artisan route:list` for other conflicting routes that may be overriding this.

Comment: Wild guess: I've never seen a route defined with the method in upper-case like that.  [The docs certainly don't use it](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing).  Try `Route::post()`, with the method in lower-case ?

Comment: my post method is POST

Comment: I throw an error when doing the php artisan route: list

Comment: @EdgarRodriguezTesta You should fix that issue, then, as it may be related.

Comment: `my post method is POST - what does this mean?  Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Don't Panic I try to put POST

Comment: @Don'tPanic when I try to execute php artisan route: list I get the following error Illuminate \ Contracts \ Container \ BindingResolutionException: Target class [Ap p \ Http \ Controllers \ Auth \ RegisterController] does not exist.

Comment: I keep asking if you tried what I first suggested, but you keep telling me about something else. See my first comment above, it is the first thing I would try. Good luck.

Comment: @Don'tPanic my route is defined with the post method in uppercase,
Route::POST('/SuperAdmin/StoreProfesor','ProfesorController@store')->name('/SuperAdmin/StoreProfesor');

Answer (score 0):

Route usage is wrong.

```
url: "{{ route('SuperAdmin.StoreProfesor') }}",
```

you should use it this way. You can also define the name by putting "."

```
Route::POST('/SuperAdmin/StoreProfesor', 'ProfesorController@store')->name('SuperAdmin.StoreProfesor');
```

Comment: thanks for the help, it still gives me the same problem

Comment: hello, first of all, thank you very much for your time, now, I would like to know how I can make an ajax request in laravel from a js file, because it does not work with the helper url: "{{route ('SuperAdmin.StoreProfesor') }} "

Answer (score 0):

I consulted a person and he answered the following, This because the external file does not recognize the Laravel helpers.
the answer is:
in my html5 file:

```
<button type="submit" id="btn_enviar" data-uri="{{ route('SuperAdmin.StoreProfesor') }}" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Enviar</button>
```

in my ajax file:

```
$('#btn_enviar').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).html('Sending..');
        var url = $(this).data('uri');
        $.ajax({
          data: $('#profesor').serialize(),
          url: url,
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {


          },
          error: function (data) {
              //console.log('Error:', data);
              $('#btn_enviar').html('Save Changes');
          }
      });
    });
```